# I can't implement un-clickable text_fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application that I have been working on and have everything wired up to my liking but was wondering if this is possible:

I am displaying a users username in an edit.html.erb template. I want it to display the users username inside of the `<%= f.text_field :username, :class=> "uneditable-input" %>`. I am using Bootstrap and in the documentation, it states to add a class of `uneditable-input`, when I hove rover the username text field, it shows a little white stop sign but I am still able to click on the field and edit it. Any help?

```
<%= render 'shared_partials/errors', errors_object: @user %>
<div class="page-header">
  <h2> Edit Your Profile<small> - <%= @user.username %></h2></small>
</div>

<div class="well">
  <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username, :class=> "uneditable-input" %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :class=> "input", :placeholder=>"Password goes here" %><br/>

    <%= f.submit "Update Changes", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the field disabled.

```
<%= f.text_field :username, :class=> "uneditable-input", :disabled => true %>
```

While submitting the form, browser will not send the value for the field username and thats correct, why it should be sent if it is un-editable.